# Switching between modes / Accessing parts of data structure

Tags: angularjs

Given the following data:

```
    {
        id:         "",
        title:      "",
        // modes
        one: {
            stage:  1,
            order:  3,
            more:   "", 
        }       
        two: {
            stage:  14,
            order:  5,
            more:   "", 
        }       
        // ...
    },
    // ...
```

how can I combine the following two pieces of code into one that uses a *variable* as a switching mechanism for the mode?

```
// If selected mode was "one"
<li ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy: ['one.stage', 'one.order'] 
| filter: oneFilter" ng-class="{ topline: isNewOneStage( item )}">
    {{ item.title }}, 
    {{ item.one.stage }}
    // ...
</li>

// If selected mode was "two"
<li ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy: ['two.stage', 'two.order'] 
| filter: twoFilter" ng-class="{ topline: isNewTwoStage( item )}">
    {{ item.title }}, 
    {{ item.two.stage }}
    // ...
</li>
```

Since the two pieces of code are completely identical - apart from the mode - I would like to avoid code duplication. (Note also that there will eventually be more than just two modes.)

Comment: I would recommend transform this data structure in a more suitable presentation. I think you have to iterate over the properties of the object and decide wether it is an object (one, two,...) or not. May be there is a solution to iterate in the way you want directly in html, but this would become unreadable code. You may do the transformation in the service that loads the data or in your controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Michael that you should probably reorganize your code, but if you must have it all at once you can do this depending on what version of angular you are using:

```
// variable mode is either 'one' or 'two'
<li ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy: [ mode + '.stage', mode + '.order'] 
| filter: (mode == 'one' ? oneFilter: twoFilter)" ng-class="{ topline: (mode == 'one' ? isNewOneStage: isNewTwoStage)( item )}">
    {{ item.title }}, 
    {{ item[mode].stage }}
    // ...
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks, once I realised that `item[mode]` is valid notation, I managed to reorganise some of my code to switch depending on mode variable. It's pretty clean now :)